Difficulty with checking if locations are within a route using Google Maps API using JS
I've implemented Google Maps API to show a map with the user's current location and allow them to search for a destination.
I use DirectionsService to calculate and display a driving route from the user's location to the destination.
I'm fetching XML data for bike stations, bus stops, and tube stations and trying to place markers for those that are close to the route.
Despite using checkDistanceToRoute, which calculates distances accurately for other points of interest (e.g., bike stations, bus stops), the function consistently determines that tube stations are not within the route, even when they should be visibly close on the map, even when I am checking for a radius of 1km of the route.
let map;
let geocoder;
let directionsService;
let directionsRenderer = null;
let markers = [];
let userLocation;
let destinationLocation;

function initMap() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    const userLat = position.coords.latitude;
    const userLng = position.coords.longitude;
    userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat, userLng);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: userLocation,
      zoom: 15,
    });

    const userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: userLocation,
      title: "Your Location",
    });

    markers.push(userMarker);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    document.getElementById("searchButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
      searchPlace();
    });

    document.getElementById("showBikePointsButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
      showBikeStations();
    });

    document.getElementById("showBusLocationsButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
      showBusLocations();
    });

    document.getElementById("showTubeLocationsButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
      showTubeLocations();
    });

  });
}

function searchPlace() {
  if (directionsRenderer) {
    directionsRenderer.setMap(null);
  }
  clearMarkers();
  clearBikePointMarkers();

  const destinationName = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;

  geocoder.geocode({ address: destinationName }, function (results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
      destinationLocation = results[0].geometry.location;

      const directionsRequest = {
        origin: userLocation,
        destination: destinationLocation,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      };
      directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function (response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          if (!directionsRenderer) {
            directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
          }
          directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

          // Calculate and display the distance
          calculateAndDisplayDistance(userLocation, destinationLocation);
        } else {
          alert("Oops, couldn't find directions due to " + status);
        }
      });

      const destinationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: destinationLocation,
        title: destinationName,
      });

      markers.push(destinationMarker);
    } else {
      alert("Oops, couldn't find that place. Try something else!");
    }
  });
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}

function showBikeStations() {
  clearMarkers();
  clearBikePointMarkers();
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const apiUrl = "https://tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/cycle-hire/livecyclehireupdates.xml";

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      const xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
      const stations = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("station");

      for (let i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
        const station = stations[i];
        const stationName = station.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent;
        const stationLat = parseFloat(station.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].textContent);
        const stationLng = parseFloat(station.getElementsByTagName("long")[0].textContent);

        const stationLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(stationLat, stationLng);

        const isWithinRange = checkDistanceToRoute(stationLocation);

        if (isWithinRange) {
          const stationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: stationLocation,
            title: stationName,
            icon: {
              url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png",
            },
          });

          markers.push(stationMarker);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  xhr.open("GET", apiUrl, true);
  xhr.send();
}

function showBusLocations() {
  clearMarkers();
  clearBikePointMarkers();

  // Replace 'bus_locations.xml' with the actual path to your XML file
  const xmlFile = "bus_locations.xml";
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      const xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
      const locationElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("location");

      if (directionsRenderer && directionsRenderer.getDirections()) {
        const route = directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0];

        for (let i = 0; i < locationElements.length; i++) {
          const location = locationElements[i];
          const stopName = location.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent;
          const stopLat = parseFloat(location.getElementsByTagName("latitude")[0].textContent);
          const stopLng = parseFloat(location.getElementsByTagName("longitude")[0].textContent);

          const busStopLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(stopLat, stopLng);

          const isWithinRange = checkDistanceToRoute(busStopLocation, route);

          if (isWithinRange) {
            const busStopMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: busStopLocation,
              title: stopName,
            });

            markers.push(busStopMarker);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  xhr.open("GET", xmlFile, true);
  xhr.send();
}

function showTubeLocations() {
  clearMarkers();
  clearBikePointMarkers();
  console.log("TUBE WORKS");

  const xmlUrl = "tubes22.xml"; // Replace with your XML file URL

  fetch(xmlUrl)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((xmlData) => {
      // Parse the XML data
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlData, "application/xml");
      const records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Record");

      console.log("Parsed XML data:", records); // Debugging line

      if (directionsRenderer && directionsRenderer.getDirections()) {
        const route = directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0];

        for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
          const record = records[i];
          const row = record.getElementsByTagName("Row")[0];
          const stationName = row.getAttribute("A");
          const latitude = parseFloat(row.getAttribute("B"));
          const longitude = parseFloat(row.getAttribute("C"));

          console.log("Station Name:", stationName); // Debugging line
          console.log("Latitude:", latitude);         // Debugging line
          console.log("Longitude:", longitude);       // Debugging line

          const tubeStopLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

          const isWithinRange = checkDistanceToRoute(tubeStopLocation, route);

          console.log("Is Within Range:", isWithinRange); // Debugging line

          if (isWithinRange) {
            const tubeStopMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: tubeStopLocation,
              title: stationName,
            });

            markers.push(tubeStopMarker);
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching or parsing XML data: ", error);
    });
}


// Adjust the distance threshold (300 meters in this example) in checkDistanceToRoute() according to your specific requirements.
function checkDistanceToRoute(location, route) {
  const routePath = route.overview_path;

  for (let i = 0; i < routePath.length; i++) {
    const point = routePath[i];
    const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location, point);
    if (distance <= 1000) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

function clearMarkers() {
  markers.forEach(marker => marker.setMap(null));
  markers = [];
}


function calculateAndDisplayDistance(origin, destination) {
  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    },
    function (response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        const distanceText = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
        document.getElementById("distanceText").textContent = `Distance to destination: ${distanceText}`;
      } else {
        alert("Error calculating distance: " + status);
      }
    }
  );
}

function checkDistanceToRoute(location) {
  if (directionsRenderer && directionsRenderer.getDirections()) {
    const route = directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
      const leg = route.legs[i];
      const steps = leg.steps;
      for (let j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
        const step = steps[j];
        const path = step.path;
        for (let k = 0; k < path.length; k++) {
          const point = path[k];
          const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location, point);
          if (distance <= 300) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function clearBikePointMarkers() {
  markers.forEach((marker) => {
    if (marker.getTitle()) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
  });

  markers = markers.filter((marker) => !marker.getTitle());
}

